# How can I get the root View from a WKInterfaceController, without an outlet

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchos

I want to get a hold of the root view of a `WKInterfaceController`, without having defined an outlet for it. I want this for a development tool I'm trying to build. Its not code I mean to run in production, so private APIs are welcome here.

Comment: @8bitcat, `WKInterfaceController` doesn't have a member called `navigationController`. Did you mean the method `popToRootController` in `WKInterfaceController`? If so, I don't see how this answers my question. The method affects the view presented, but I don't get a reference to that view, which is what I'm after. In addition, it has the side effect of changing the UI, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 4):

I hope that below code will help you.

```
WKExtension *sharedExtention = [WKExtension sharedExtension];
WKInterfaceController *rootInterfaceController = sharedExtention.rootInterfaceController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0.1 version...

```
if let yourInterfaceController = WKExtension.shared().rootInterfaceController as? YourInterfaceController {
  nowInterfaceController.yourMethod()
}
```